# Angular NgIf template with several conditions

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
<dl>
  <dt>vehicle.value | translate</dt>
  <dd>vehicle.id</dd>

  <dt>status.value | translate</dt>
  <dd>vehicle.status</dd>
</dl>
```

The `vehicle.id` can take three different values let's assume A,B,C and the `vehicle.status` depends on what value the `vehicle.id` takes, i.e. if it takes the value A it will display e.g. letter 1 if the value B is letter 2 etc.

And now I'm wondering if it makes sense to make such an ifa in html or is it better to make the function in typescript and use it in html? What would such a pseduocode look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the condition is simple and not dynamic, you could manage that inside the HTML and with `ngSwitch`. Otherwise, I would say it better to deal the value of the `status` directly when you get your value in your `.ts`

```
<dl>
  <dt>vehicle.value | translate</dt>
  <dd>vehicle.id</dd>

  <dt>status.value | translate</dt>
  <container-element [ngSwitch]="vehicle.id">
     <dd *ngSwitchCase="A">1</dd>
     <dd *ngSwitchCase="B">2</dd>
     <dd *ngSwitchCase="C">3</dd>
  </container-element>
</dl>
```

Comment: And if the condition is complex I recommend to use a pipe with vehicle.id as a parameter.